# low level embedded drawing library

Tags: library, images, image-processing, drawing

for visualisation purpose I need low level embedded drawing library (preferably written in C) for real time working , I would be calculating some data and than makeing histograms , for this I need an software or tool ?

And how should I do it (how to make graphical image from data in real time)?

Comment: "Embedded" like AVR + Nokia SPI display or more like 4-core Cortex A53 SoC with LVDS?

Comment: @TMSZ I am having ARM processor dual core A-9 + FPGA .

Comment: if still relevant: try imlib2, it might fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

[Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/) Graphics is written in C and have a rich feature set - while it certainly can offer what you need, maybe it is overkill (I think it requires glib - the base framework for Gnome utilities), and may be too big for your purposes.

[Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/) is a fairly simpler library resource and requisites wise, but have a different purpose - it is more fit for image analysis than creation and drawing - I am not even sure it have a drawing API.

If you find both unfit, please, just comment bellow and I might trying searching further.

Comment: I read about libs that  you mentioned above , these are probably not what I need , actually I have data for ploting graphs and I need a drawing lib to plot a graphical representation  of the graph to visualise it. Every this should be fast as things are in real time .

Comment: Over the last 2 weeks I had actually been writtingbasic graphics code - that allows one to plot functions, on my spare time. This code is on a completly different context (it is Python code, and to draw on the text terminal with unicode chars). Still I am on it and the drawing algorithms are the same - if no suitable library like what you need is found, I could work on that instead - the algorithms are the same. Can you say more about the pixel data format you hae to deal with?

Comment: And, other questoin, does your target platform supports hardware floating point numbers or is it integer arithmetic only?

Comment: Thanks for replying , I am having ARM processor dual core A-9 + FPGA (no GPU) , and I need to plot graphs in real time and it's integer airthmetic only. These are constrains which I have to take into consideration , can you send me your algorithm I will try to implement it on C .